# How to run two functions in parallel in python

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-multiprocessing, ros2

I am creating a simulation with two robots(using ROS2 Iron and on gazebo) who will play Capture the Flag game. I have a python API that sends them navigation tasks, however, the navigation tasks don't start at the same time. I want both of the robots to start navigating together.

This is an example of what I want to run:

```
navigator1.goThroughPoses(goal_pose1)  #Sends navigation command to one robot
navigator2.goThroughPoses(goal_pose2)  #Sends navigation command to the other robot
```

I basically want to run these two processes in parallel so that both the robots start navigation at the same time.
Further context: I am using [Simple Commander API](https://navigation.ros.org/commander_api/index.html) to send navigation commands through the robot.

Comment: you've not given many details, I'm struggling to know what to suggest!  I also note that the "ros2" tag says to use https://robotics.stackexchange.com/ when asking questions, suggesting you will probably have more luck asking there

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you asked the same question here https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/24972